# How do I upload a file to sql with this error message?

Tags: sql, csv, upload

Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

This is the error message when I type it into SQL to create a table from my csv format document.

Comment: Welcome. Please take time to read the guide to writing a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently yours is lacking context, so it's hard to provide a good answer, but with some tweaks it will be okay! Some things to tell us: what type of SQL database are you using (you could add this as a tag)? What is the actual SQL command you are using to do the upload? What have you tried so far based on the research you did before asking here? It looks like the upload is failing due to a null ASCII character in your CSV, but the fix will depend on the database you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.